# How Can I do Summary Components in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to create a component that will summarize content from other components, but i don't know how to properly do this.

if there is a more proper way, please let me know rather than solving this one. TIA!

For now, I'm trying to create this by passing the other components to the summary component through @Input, but it doesn't get passed, here is my code:

here is the [application](https://stackblitz.com/github/jpasol/sbitcChecklist)

stepper.html

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper>

  <mat-step [stepControl]="breakdownsGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="breakdownsGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Breakdowns</ng-template>
      <app-breakdowns formArrayName="breakdowns"></app-breakdowns>
    </form>
  </mat-step>

  <mat-step [stepControl]="summaryGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="summaryGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Summary</ng-template>
      <app-summary [breakdowns]="breakdowns"></app-summary>
    </form>
  </mat-step>

</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

stepper.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import { format } from 'url';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stepper',
  templateUrl: './stepper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stepper.component.css']
})
export class StepperComponent implements OnInit {

  isLinear = false;

  remarksGroup: FormGroup;
  breakdownsGroup: FormGroup;
  summaryGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.breakdownsGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      breakdowns: this._formBuilder.array([])
    })
    this.summaryGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      summary: this._formBuilder.array([])
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

summary.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-summary',
  templateUrl: './summary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./summary.component.css']
})
export class SummaryComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() remarks;
  @Input() breakdowns;

  ngOnChanges() {
  }
  showBreakdowns(){
    console.log(this.breakdowns)
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `<app-breakdowns formArrayName="breakdowns"></app-breakdowns>` try to pass the entire form group: `<app-breakdowns formArrayName="breakdownsGroup"></app-breakdowns>`. This way you can use form group inside your child component

Comment: Tried it, it resulted in finding the child compnent `breakdownsGroup`

`ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'breakdownsGroup'`

Comment: Sorry i've pasted the wrong line of your code. Try to pass the entire form group in `<app-summary [breakdowns]="breakdownsGroup"></app-summary>`.

Comment: great! `<app-summary [breakdowns]="breakdownsGroup"></app-summary>` did pass the whole FormGroup, but even though i tried populating the Breakdown Component (which is what i'm trying to summarize), there are no controls being populated

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is in the line `<app-summary [breakdowns]="breakdowns"></app-summary>` in `stepper.html`. The way this is actually working is as follows:

[*TS variable named 'breakdowns' in summary.ts*] = "*TS variable named 'breakdowns' in stepper.ts*"

You might notice that there not actually a class-level variable called `breakdown` in `stepper.ts`. There is however a variable `breakdownsGroup` which contains within it a FormArray with the name `breakdown`. So really, in order to give `stepper.html` something it recognises, what we want to pass into the right side of the above line is instead:

`<app-summary [breakdowns]="breakdownsGroup?.controls?.breakdown?.value"></app-summary>`

A more elegant way of achieving the same is to use an alias `get` function in your typescript to reference the form control you are interested in. You can then use this alias to shorten the code in your HTML, like so:

**stepper.ts**

```
get breakdowns() {
  return this.breakdownsGroup.get('breakdowns')
}
```

**stepper.html**

```
<app-summary [breakdowns]="breakdowns?.value"></app-summary>
```

You should now be able to access the contents of the `breakdowns` FormArray from within `summary.ts`.

*Note however, there is currently no logic in `stepper.ts` which either assigns nor modifies `breakdownsGroup` or the `breakdowns` FormArray, therefore you will only have the initialised blank array passed into `summary.ts`*

Comment: i tried this solution, though this really passes the `breakdowns` form array stated in my `stepper.ts`, the actual form group which i supposedly assigned the form group `<app-breakdowns formArrayName="breakdowns"></app-breakdowns>` is not getting reflected. thanks ! i think i'm getting there, i just need to reflect the values from `<app-breakdowns></app-breakdowns>`